# Is there a way to use a colour scheme on an application without having to individually write the colour values on each part of the code?

Tags: ios, swift, colors

I am developing a Single View application with multiple screens. I want to make use of multiple shades of blue within the application. Right now I'm accessing the UIColor/cgColor property of each view within the multiple viewControllers to assign a particular colour.
eg:

```
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 178/255, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
```

and,

```
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 128/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

and,

```
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

I wish to know if there is a way to define all the colours without multiple lines of codes all across the multiple view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [appearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) proxy. Please refer to documentation on how you can use it, like:

```swift
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
```

You would probably also want to extend [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor) with your custom colors like:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    class var customColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 178/255, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a struct to create static values

```swift
struct AppThemeColor{
    static func cellLayerColor() -> UIColor{
        return UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 178/255, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    }

    static func cellBackgroundColor() -> UIColor{
        return UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 128/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
    // ...
}
```

To get the color is simples

```swift
cell.backgroundColor = AppThemeColor.cellBackgroundColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best way would be to create color extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var borderColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 178/255, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    }
    static var backgroundColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 128/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.borderColor.cgColor
cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundColor.cgColor
```

For more general approach you can use UIAppearance protocol, eg. for your case you would create extension

```
extension UITableViewCell {

    @objc public var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set { layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor }
        get { return layer.borderColor.map({ UIColor(cgColor: $0)}) }
    }

    @objc public var layerBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        set { layer.backgroundColor = newValue?.cgColor }
        get { return layer.backgroundColor.map({ UIColor(cgColor: $0)}) }
    }
}
```

and then use it in code:

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().borderColor = UIColor.borderColor
UITableViewCell.appearance().layerBackgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundColor
```

For more details you can take a look at:
[UIAppearance](https://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)
and
[Styling your app using custom UIAppearance properties](https://nachbaur.com/2019/04/22/styling-with-uiappearance/)